# When inserting data using SQLBulkCopy into an Azure SQL Database table I am getting an error message "The wait operation timed out"?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, sqlbulkcopy

When I insert more than 80000 records into an Azure SQL Database table using the below code:

```cs
IEnumerable<SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping> columnMapping;
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table dbo.Site");
columnMapping = openXmlParse.GetSiteServiceColumnMappings();
bulkCopy.BatchSize = 2000;
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Site";
bulkCopy.WriteTableToServer(dt, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, columnMapping);
db.sp_TrimTableColumns("Site");
```

In local DB it works fine but an exception is thrown when the code is run against Azure SQL Database.

Comment: What is the service tier of the database you are inserting data into? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-service-tiers/

Comment: This is a query timeout, I suggest checking sys.dm_db_resource_stats to see if anything is maxed out.

Comment: Post the exception ToString. Insufficient error information. This has lead to a wrong answer already. Wait timeout != command timeout. What's `db.sp_TrimTableColumns("Site");` supposed to be? That's not C#.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly set the command timeout to larger value based on how long it takes. .Net default value is 30 seconds and may not be sufficient for large inserts. The command run time varies on the service objective chosen too.